# Como fazer quebras de linha no createTextNode?

Tags: array, números-aleatórios

Estou tentando quebrar a linha para que fique assim:

```
pergunta

resposta<br>,resposta<br>,resposta<br>,resposta
```

só que quando eu coloco o 
 aparece assim

```
Pergunta

resposta br, resposta br, resposta br, resposta
```

> OBS: TENTEI usar o JOIN("br"), também saiu escrito o que estava dentro.

```js
var questions1 = [

  {
    pergunta: "questao1:",
    resp: [
      "a) 1 ",
      "b) 11 ",
      "c) 111 ",
      "d) 1111 ",
      "e) 11111 "
    ]
  },

  {
    pergunta: "questão2:",
    resp: [
      "a) 2.",
      "b) 22.",
      "c) 222.",
      "d) 2222",
      "e) 22222"
    ]
  },

  {
    pergunta: "questão3:",
    resp: [
      "a) 3.",
      "b) 33.",
      "c) 333.",
      "d) 3333",
      "e) 33333"
    ]
  },

  {
    pergunta: "questão4:",
    resp: [
      "a) 4.",
      "b) 44.",
      "c) 444.",
      "d) 4444",
      "e) 44444"
    ]
  },

];

var subset = select(4, questions1);

outputQuestions(subset);

function select(n, qarray) {
  var subset = [];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (qarray.length));
    subset[subset.length] = qarray[randomIdx];
    qarray.splice(randomIdx, 1);
  }
  return subset;
}

document.body.onload = adcElemento;

function shuffled(arr) {
  arr = arr.slice(); // shallow copy
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - i)) + i;
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]; // swap
  }
  return arr;


}

function outputQuestions(subset) {

  for (k in subset) {

    var quest = document.getElementById("questoes");

    quest.appendChild(document.createTextNode(". " + subset[k].pergunta));
    quest.appendChild(document.createElement("P"));

    //aqui que não estou conseguindo fazer a quebra de linha das respostas

    quest.appendChild(document.createTextNode(shuffled(subset[k].resp)));
    quest.appendChild(document.createElement("p"))

  }





}
```

```html
<p id="questoes">

</p>
```

como eu faria essa quebra de linha? alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Boas-vindas. É importante **[edit] e reformular a pergunta seguindo exatamente as orientações em: [mcve] (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)**. Se tiver corrigido adequadamente, sua pergunta será avaliada por 5 usuários para reabertura na [fila de analises](/help/reviews-intro). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Comment: continuo sem entender, pra mim não tinha erros na pergunta.

quebra de linha

Comment: Não tem como saber se tem ou não erros no seu código, porque o problema da pergunta não é compreensível e não é possível para outras pessoas reproduzirem seus códigos. Isso porque a pergunta não segue o modelo [mcve]. Observe que o campo de comentários não deve ser usado para meta-assuntos, ou seja, não deve ser usado para debater dúvidas de como usar o site Stack Overflow em Português e nem questionar motivos de fechamentos, o que deve fazer é seguir as orientações, [edit] e melhorar a pergunta e aguardar a avaliação de 5 usuários na fila de analises.

Comment: A conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142027/discussion-on-question-by-leo-vince-quebra-de-linha-no-createtextnode)